# Can't find online documentation for log4j version 1.2

Tags: log4j

There is a link to documentation on log4j wiki, but it's broken.
Wiki is here: http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/

Probably since log4j 2 was introduced.

Does anybody know where is that documentation located now?

EDIT:
I can google and can find log4j2 documentation. I want to find documentation for log4j version 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

(and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2 for the main page)